# What's the "biggest change we've ever made" in Magic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, history

I'm currently catching up on Head Designer Mark Rosewater's "Drive to Work" podcast. I've been out of the loop for about a year.

In Episode 460: Announcements, which aired in August of 2017, he says:

> "There is a big revamp in behind the scenes of how we make Magic. A
>   big one. Like, probably the biggest we’ve had since I have worked at
>   Wizards."

He goes on to say that he will write an article in the fall to announce it, and that it's "the biggest change we've ever made."

Well, fall has come and gone and I'm still clueless. I've perused MaRo's articles from August through now, but I still haven't found anything that indicates or announces any sort of major paradigm shift.

**What is the big change MaRo is referring to?** And, if possible, **What articles/podcasts cover this announcement?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was to do with Vision design (see podcast #495 and #496) and the introduction of the design play team. There's an article [here](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/vision-design-set-design-and-play-design-2017-10-23) where Maro talks about it from October of 2017.

It's a very interesting article and gives me high hopes for the future of Standard considering how much of an issue they've been having in terms of creating balanced and fun Constructed environments recently.

Comment: Checked both of these out and my question is answered. One thing, though: The Vision Design appears to also be discussed as early as #495 (Vision, Set, and Play Design)

Comment: Ah, my bad, I just flicked to the first podcast I saw Vision on as I knew it weas recent, I'll update my answer